# Trying to search any word present in all of my elasticsearch documents (no field specified) in c# using NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to search an input word in any index or document in elasticsearch using NEST in c#

I've already tried `simple_string_query`, `match_all`, `_search` (most basic request), none of this worked and I get every time the same error message.

```cs
var conn = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("<elasticsearchEndpoint>))
                .DefaultIndex(model.Index)
                .DefaultTypeName(model.Type);
var client = new ElasticClient(conn);
var res = client.Search<dynamic*>(c=>c
                .AllIndices()
                .AllTypes()
                .Query(q=>q
                    .QueryString(qs=>qs.Query(model.Query)
                )
));
```

I've also tried with myObject class

I expect to get a list of documents that contains the input word, or at least a list of document ids.

You will find the error below :

> Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException : 'Cannot deserialize
>   the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Int64' because 
>   the type requires a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) to 
>   deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, 
>   number, boolean, null) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal 
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an 
>   array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. 
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize 
>   from a JSON object.
>   Path 'hits.total.value', line 1, position 116.'

Comment: Is this the full stack trace ? Can you add it ?

Comment: Also what is model ? Can you give it here in Json format or sth ? In particular model.Query prop is of interest to me.

Comment: @korulis Yes this is the full stack trace, model.Query is the input word (ex: "France")

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public class ApiModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Index")]
    public string Index { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public dynamic Body { get; set; }
    public string sent_body { get; set; }
    public bool Request { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public string Rody { get; set; }
    public string Query { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you should add this to your question so everything is in one place.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are using a NEST 6.x client against Elasticsearch 7.x. This won't work because they are not compatible; in this case, I suspect it is the change to the `"total"` field on a search response that cannot be deserialized because [in 7.x it is an `object` and in 6.x, it is a `long`](https://www.elastic.co/blog/faster-retrieval-of-top-hits-in-elasticsearch-with-block-max-wand).

Please use a NEST 7.x client with Elasticsearch 7.x, which is compatible. The latest at this time is [7.0.0-beta1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/7.0.0-beta1).

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try